# How to apply window function/ or non window function in MySQL to solve below problem?

Tags: mysql, sql

The table below is for different brands of milk tea stores' profits. How to use MySQL to calculate the different profits between (milkA + milkB) and milkC based on each date.  (how to use both non window function and window function to approach in such case)

Sample milk_tea table:

| timeDate | brand_name | profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | milkA | 400 |
| 2020-01-01 | milkB | 200 |
| 2020-01-01 | milkC | 300 |
| 2020-01-02 | milkA | 200 |
| 2020-01-02 | milkB | 300 |
| 2020-01-02 | milkC | 100 |
| .... |  |  |

For example: for timeDate 2020-01-01,  the different is equal to (400 + 200) - 300 = 300;

400 is the profit of milkA(brand_name),
200 is the profit of milkB(brand_name),
300 is the profit of milkC(brand_name).

Notes:

1. Assume all columns have the correct types like timeDate in Date type.
2. There could be another brand_name milk tea stores like milkD, milkE.
3. Assume no null value in all columns

Sample code for defining the table in MySQL:

```
create table milk_tea(
   timeDate DATE,
   brand_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   profit INT
);

INSERT INTO milk_tea VALUES ('2020-01-01', 'milkA', 400);
INSERT INTO milk_tea VALUES ('2020-01-01', 'milkB', 200);
INSERT INTO milk_tea VALUES ('2020-01-01', 'milkC', 300);
INSERT INTO milk_tea VALUES ('2020-01-02', 'milkA', 200);
INSERT INTO milk_tea VALUES ('2020-01-02', 'milkB', 300);
INSERT INTO milk_tea VALUES ('2020-01-02', 'milkC', 100);
```

Desired output:

| timeDate | diff_profit |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 300 |
| 2020-01-02 | 400 |
| .... |  |

Can someone please provide me with some MySQL code? Thanks a lot

Comment: (Edit) What have you tried so far, and how was the result different than what you expected? `There could be another brand_name milk tea stores like milkD, milkE.` The original formula was (milkA + milkB) - milkC. What do you expect the results to be if there are 5 types (MilkA, MilkB, MilkC, MilkD, MilkE) ... or 6 ... or more - and more importantly why?

Comment: You asked exactly the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71366132/how-to-use-both-window-function-and-non-window-function-in-mysql-to-solve-below). It was closed as a duplicate, because it was essentially asking the same as had already been answered before. Look at the answers given, and try to apply them to your case. If you get stuck, come back and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation (a boolean expression inside the aggregate function):

```
select
  timedate,
  sum(case when brand_name in ('milkA', 'milkB') then profit end) as profit_ab,
  sum(case when brand_name = 'milkC' then profit end) as profit_c,
  sum(case when brand_name = 'milkC' then -profit else profit end) as diff
from milk_tea
where brand_name in ('milkA', 'milkB', 'milkC') 
group by timedate
order by timedate;
```

Comment: thank you! it works!! Meanwhile, not sure whether we can use the window function to approach this question as well.

Comment: Well, you can probably write some query including window functions, but why would you do this? The difference between aggregation functions and window / analytic functions is that the former aggregate your rows, while the latter keep the rows and only add agregation information. You *want* to aggregate your rows in order to get one result row per timedate, so why muddle through with analytic functions?

Comment: thanks for explaining the details.  I guess in this case window function will be properly involved.

Answer (score 0):

You may use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    timeDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN brand_name = 'milkA' THEN profit ELSE 0 END) +
    MAX(CASE WHEN brand_name = 'milkB' THEN profit ELSE 0 END) -
    MAX(CASE WHEN brand_name = 'milkC' THEN profit ELSE 0 END) AS diff_profit
FROM milk_tea
GROUP BY timeDate
ORDER BY timeDate;
```